# Average between columns in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I need to calculate an average grade for 3 grades that student received.

```
ID      subject     G1  G2  G3
12345   Math        90  80  77
12345   Physics     99  89  78
12345   Network     76  60  90
99999   Math        50  90  88
99999   Chemistry   80  70  88
88888   English     90  90  100
88888   Physics     90  89  79
```

those are the entries in MySQL database, i need a way to calculate an average for those entries per each row between 3 columns

so when the output retrieves on the web it looks like this

```
subject     gradeone    gradetwo    gradethree  average
Math        90          80          77
```

any help is appreciated! many thanks!

Comment: protip: Look at [`AVG`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function.

Comment: @BradChristie looked.. doesnt quite work tho

Comment: You could always `(g1+g2+g3)/3`

Comment: @BradChristie `AVG` only works for column averages

Comment: @SavTheCoder: My apologies, but I was assuming there weren't 3 fixed Gn columns.

Comment: @BradChristie could you write SQL statement

Comment: thank you guys, 2nd question to this part is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728951/while-loop-and-join-output-in-mysql-php   @BradChristie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4f89b/1/0)

```
SELECT subject,
       g1 as gradeone,
       g2 as gradetwo,
       g3 as gradethree,
       (g1+g2+g3)/3 as average
FROM   students
```

Result:

```
SUBJECT     GRADEONE  GRADETWO  GRADETHREE  AVERAGE
Math        90        80        77          82.3333
Physics     99        89        78          88.6667
Network     76        60        90          75.3333
Math        50        90        88          76
Chemistry   80        70        88          79.3333
English     90        90        100         93.3333
Physics     90        89        79          86
```

Comment: @Brad - I'm just curious as to why the headers all come up in uppercase.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: SqlFiddle does it natively--not sure why.

Comment: @BradChristie That's what I thought, I was going to edit my comment in saying if it was proprietary to the server it's on; thank you. +1 for your answer btw, answers/questions like these can prove to be very useful, cheers.

Comment: @TimValishin: if you ever wanted a better way to organize the information without being fixated on only three grades: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee3caf/2/0

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT subject,
       G1 AS gradeone,
       G2 AS gradetwo,
       G3 AS gradethree,
       ((G1 + G2 + G3) / 3) AS average
FROM   tablename;
```

Assuming that you never have more than three test scores, this will give you the output you wanted for every student.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql like-

```
select subject, 
       g1 as gradeone, 
       g2 as gradetwo, 
       g3 as gradethree, 
       ((g1+g2+g3)/3) as average 
from tablename where id=12345;
```